# Javascript if statement not validating correct

Tags: javascript, jquery

This little JS is meant to be run when a user clicks on a button. First I check whether an element is visible or not - then I show/hide it according to the check.

The problem is that the if statement validates to FALSE everytime - even though the else statement sets the style.display to exactly what I'm asking for in the if statement.

In my simple world the statement shall return true every second time it is run...

```
if (d[0].style.diplay == 'block') {
    $(d[0]).slideUp('slow');
} else {
    d[0].style.display = 'block';       
}
```

What am I overseeing?

Comment: what is d[0]? if d[0] is a DOM object then how can you use it on $(d[0]) or if its a querystring, how can you use it as d[0].style.display == 'block' ? and note that style.display can hold values other than block too.

Comment: @Ronnie `$()` accepts DOM objects as the parameter.

Comment: `var d = document.getElementsByClassName('.level4_class');`

Comment: Anyway, it's just a typo. diplay !== di**s**play

Comment: Okay, i see. But is it a good idea to do that? Switch between jQuery and JavaScript? I, frankly, never did. I think, a jQuery object can just be used as a DOM element (by iterating over). That just helps maintain readability. anyways thanks. I never learnt this.

Comment: holy smoke... just forget I ever asked... been staring at this for 15 minutes now :(

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Beside the `diplay` typo... (missing `s`)</sup>
When doing `slideUp` you can go directly for `.is(":visible")`
Depends on what you want (not cleat from what your current Question) but see this:

```
var $el = $(d[0]);
if( $el.is(":visible") ){
    // is visible
}else{
    // is slided up (not visible)
}
```

you could also simply `slideToggle()`

```
var $el = $(d[0]);
$el.slideToggle();
```

You can check for a CSS rule using jQuery, you know...

```
var elDisplay = $el.css("display"); // "none", "block", "inline-block" ...
```

---

Since I see you use jQuery already... not needed but it's meant to make your life easier - so instead of `var d = document.getElementsByClassName('.level4_class');`

use

```
var $el = $('.level4_class');
```

done that you can than access the desired CSS property from a `.css()` Method callback:

```
$el.css("display", function(index, displayValue){ // Iterates over all .level4_class el.
    if( displayValue==="block") { // ...checking for "block" value
       // do something using $(this)
    }
});
```

***[jsbin demo](https://jsbin.com/tihuzoh/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

Comment: `.is(":visible")` does the trick - but I still can't seem to understand why the other statement validates to FALSE. I should be pretty sure that display is set to block when doing it myself in the else statement ;) The website code does also say block after the script is fired for the first time.

Comment: @UlrikPedersen you can always add more basic code like HTML, CSS, and more jQ/JS to create a playable test case.

Comment: @UlrikPedersen please read carefully https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/